# js2 mode doesn't recognize variable in "for in" statement

Tags: javascript, js2-mode

When I use a *for in* statement, js2 mode doesn't recognize the new variable:

```
let foo = {bar: 1};

for(key in foo) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

It prints:
*Undeclared variable or function 'key'*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It warns you that the `key` variable is undeclared, and using it like this, you leak it into the global namespace.

Try this is your browser console:

```
> let foo = {bar: 1};

> for(key in foo) {}

> key
=> "bar"
```